# Flash 10 Attaching a png file from an external swf compiled with swfmill

Tags: resources, flash, assets, swfmill

I wish to load an external swf compiled with swfmill, at run time. In other words, loading it asynchronously (not compiled together with the file). This swf contains 2 assets: file1.png and file2.png.

It's mostly working, except for this problem: how to attach the resources in the file? Normally I would use attach()…

```
var _urlLoader = new URLLoader();
var _urlRequest = new URLRequest("libgfx.swf");
_urlLoader.load(_urlRequest);
_urlLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onComplete);

public function onComplete(e:Event) {
    trace("Received shared libgfx.swf. Length: " + _urlLoader.data.length);  // displaying the size correctly

    var displayObjectLoader:Loader = new Loader();
    displayObjectLoader.load(_urlRequest);
    var displayObject:DisplayObject = addChild(displayObjectLoader);

    // How would you attach file1.png or file2.png?
    // …?
}
```

Any help appreciated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Convert the assets to MovieClip.
- Add Linkage for them.
- Use the following code to load it:

  ```
  var context:LoaderContext       = new LoaderContext( );
      context.applicationDomain   = ApplicationDomain.currentDomain;

  var loader : Loader = new Loader( );
      loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, complete );
      loader.load( new URLRequest( "assets.swf" ), context );

      function complete ( e:Event ) : void
      {
          var Asset : Class = e.target.applicationDomain.getDefinition("the linkage of the asset") as Class;
          var asset : MovieClip = new Asset( );
          addChild( asset );
      }
  ```

Hope this helps.

Cheers

Tamas Gronas